# android open gl es 2.0 height map (pragmatic programmers) book

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Open GL ES 2.0 for Android and have a question specifically about height maps.  On page 239 it explains how to Generate indices from a bitmap image. page 12 of this PDF http://media.pragprog.com/titles/kbogla/heightmap.pdf.  Why is it necessary to subtract one from width and height. I have looked through google, read this page multiple times the example given is a 3x3 heightmap where (width - 1) * (height - 1) * 2 * 3 = 24 elements <- this is stumbling me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a representation of a 3 x 3 heightmap, having 9 vertices:

[image]

Every group of 4 vertices in the height map needs 2 triangles and each triangle needs 3 indices to define it, so 6 indices in total. I've illustrated that in the first group above.

As you can see, there are 4 of these groups to do, hence 6 x 4 = 24 indices in all. Hence the number of groups to index is (width -1) x (height -1) with 6 indices per group.

Comment: Thanks Nigel for spending the time to answer.  Your explanation is crystal clear and makes perfect sense, Wish I could vote you up.

Comment: You can't vote me up with only 1 rep, but you can accept my answer, which would be just as welcome and you'll get +2 rep yourself.